# How can I add boundaries to fullscreen mode in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code:

```py
import pygame
    

pygame.init()


window_size=(800,600)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)

player_X=200
player_Y=300
player_X_change=0
player_Y_change=0


running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False


        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_X_change=-1
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_X_change=1
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                player_Y_change=-1
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_Y_change=1
        if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT or event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_X_change=0
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP or event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_Y_change=0


    screen.fill((0,200,255))

    player_X+=player_X_change
    player_Y+=player_Y_change
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (player_X, player_Y, 40, 50))
    if player_X<=-1:
        player_X=0
    if player_X>=761:
        player_X=760
    if player_Y<=-1:
        player_Y=0
    if player_Y>=551:
        player_Y=550
    
    
        pygame.display.update()
```

Now I want to add the boundaries to fullscreen mode.
I know that I can do fullscreen by:

```py
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(window_size,pygame.RESIZABLE,32).
```

Well, now I have two questions.

- First, and the main one, How can I make the boundaries while in the maximized form.
- Second, what is the use of 32 (the 3rd argument I've given in the set_mode function)?

I used it as I saw it in a tutorial. When I remove it, it doesn't do anything different but if it does then what is it/what it would be?
Well, back to the main question, when I try to go to the x axis more than 800 or the y axis more than
600 in the fullscreen mode,(which i got by resizing) i am not able to go further as the boundary ive added is for 800 by 600 window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `screen` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. Use [`get_size()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size) to get the current size of the window:

```py
running=True
while running:
    # [...]

    player_X += player_X_change
    player_Y += player_Y_change
    
    width, height = screen.get_size()
    if player_X < 0:
        player_X = 0
    if player_X > width - 40:
        player_X = width - 40
    if player_Y < 0:
        player_Y = 0
    if player_Y > height - 50:
        player_Y = height - 50    

    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (player_X, player_Y, 40, 50))
```

---

The 3rd argument of [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) is the number of bits to use for the color. You don't need to specify it at all. See the documentation of [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode):

> It is usually best to not pass the depth argument. It will default to the best and fastest color depth for the system. If your game requires a specific color format you can control the depth with this argument. Pygame will emulate an unavailable color depth which can be slow.